# Visual Studio iOS Automatic Provisioning Certificate password

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, code-signing-certificate

I want to build Xamarin.Forms iOS app on MS App center. It requires a provisioning profile and a p12 certificate. I am using Visual Studio Automatic Provisioning. I am unable to figure out how to get the certificate generated by visual studio automatic provisioning with private key to upload to MS APP Center.

Edit : I see the visual studio created certificate in the apple developer account but it's a .cert file with no private key

Comment: You have to export it from the Keychain Assistant on the Mac.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/code-signing

Comment: @jason I don't have a mac connected. I am trying to build it on App Center

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to set this up without a Mac.

Comment: i will follow the article and let you know if it works